# How to Sum nodes in firebase firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I am making app for ordering pizza.

[image]
Like you see on image i want to take all key values named "ukupno" from each document and Sum it for final price.

This is how i fetch cart data:

```
  this.cartService.getCart(this.user.Uid).subscribe(res => {
      this.cart = res.map(i => {
        return {
          ...i.payload.doc.data(),
          id: i.payload.doc.id
        };
      });
    });
  }
 getCart(uid) {
    return this.firestore
      .collection("cart/")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("/ubaceno")
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways to sum up the value of a document field for all documents of a collection:

**1/ Query for the entire collection**, loop over the result (i.e. the [`querySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)), e.g. with `forEach()`, and sum all the field values in the loop. To do that with angularfire2 you would probably use [`snapshotChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges).

**However**, If your collection contains a lot of documents, this is not very efficient and moreover it will cost one document read per document in your collection.

**2/ Use some [Distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters)** to keep an up-to-date sum for all your documents. To implement this approach, you have to update the counter each time you create/modify/delete a document in the `ubaceno` collection, adding or subtracting the value of the `ukupno` field to/from the counter.

You could do that either by having a set of Cloud Functions that update the counters upon Creation/Modification/Deletion, or by integrating in your write/modify/delete code in your front end the transaction for the counter update.

Comment: Very useful answer. I've a question for solution #2. Is there the possibility that however the data will become asynchron according to the separated counter and the actual fields?