# Firebase php sum field coins

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, count

i have a table with 90.000 records and every record has a field call coins, i need to get the sum of all coins, i am reading that i need to iterate every record and sum, but is not eficient because my database is increasing  and i need to get this value in real time.

is there a simil to select count(*)  for firebase?

thanks.[image]

Comment: The screenshot seems to be for Realtime Database, but you tagged with Cloud Firestore. While the answer happens to be the same for both databases, please make sure to tag correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore don't have built-in aggregation (like sum or count) operations. If you want to be able to load an aggregate with a simple read operation, you should store the aggregate value in the database, and update it on every relevant write operation.

This has been covered a bunch of times before as well as in the documentation, so I recommend checking out:

- [How to Implement SUM() function of SQL in cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore)
- [How to Sum nodes in firebase firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311875/how-to-sum-nodes-in-firebase-firestore)
- [How to aggregate queries in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975159/how-to-aggregate-queries-in-firebase)